# How to derive the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality from the Hölder inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

First we have proved Jensens's inequality:

If $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function and $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ positive numbers with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i=1$ and $x_1,...,x_n\in I$ then

$$f(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ix_i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}f(x_i)$$

With that we have proved that if $x_1,...,x_n>0$ and $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n>0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i=1$ then

$$x_1^{\lambda_1}\cdot …\cdot x_n^{\lambda_n}\leq\lambda_1x_1+...+\lambda_nx_n$$

Let $p,q> 1,1/p+1/q =1\wedge z=(z_1,...,z_n),w=(w_1,...,w_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$

Hölder inequality says:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_kw_k|\leq \big{(}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_k|^p\big{)}^{\frac{1}{p}}\big{(}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|w_k|^q\big{)}^{\frac{1}{q}}$$

My first Question what is the idea behind this inequality?

My second Question is that if $p=q=2$ the book says that the Hölder inequality is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality which is

$$|\sum_{k=1}^{n}z_k\overline{w_k}|\leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_k|^2}\cdot\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n}|w_k|^2$$

But why is $|\sum_{k=1}^{n}z_k\overline{w_k}|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_kw_k|$ ?

To me it only makes sense that we have $\leq$ because of the triangle inequality. More precisely:

$|\sum_{k=1}^{n}z_k\overline{w_k}|\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_k\overline{w_k}|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_kw_k|$

How can I prove $\geq$?

Source: Königsberger Analysis 1 p.161

Comment: Since $|w_k| = |\overline{w_k}|$, you can just apply the Holder inequality with $p=q=2,\ (z_1,\dots,z_n)$ and $(\overline{w_1},\dots,\overline{w_n})$.

Comment: $\geq$ does not hold, but here you only need  $\leq$ to make cauchy-schwartz follow immediately from Hölder.